# Interacting with Web pages using selenium inside electron application

Tags: javascript, selenium, electron, automated-tests

I want to create an electron application which contains a sidebar and a improvised Web browser next to the sidebar. When a user presses the button in the sidebar i need selenium to start Interacting with the webpage in the improvised browser.
I would like to know if its possible and if there are any tools that might help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium is using browser's driver to make the connection between your code and the browser. I haven't heard about anything similar to your project, but you will need to make your own driver for your custom browser and define from where the browser is opened (since it will be located inside your application, not on local machine)